# How to create a trigger to insert a value inside a json in POSTGRESQL

Tags: json, database, postgresql, triggers

I don't know how to do this.

I have a table with fields id, json

In json I have this kind of things `{"name":name1","type":"type1"}`

And I would like when an insert is performed, to add the main id in the json, so have a json like this `{"name":name1","type":"type1","id":1}`

So in my table I'll have this row :

```
ID       JSON
1        {"name":name1","type":"type1","id":1}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you read documentation for triggers and json? What problems are you having?

Comment: I didn't manage to add a property with a value in json with postgre json functions

Comment: Can you change type of this column to `jsonb`? It has built-in concatation operator and you can simply do this: `select '{"name":"name1","type":"type1"}'::jsonb || '{"id":1}'`